# How to stop statements within a Python with context from executing?

Tags: python

I've some code like this:

```
with SomeContext(args):
  <statement1>
  .
  .
  <statementN>
```

I want this code to behave like this:

```
if some_condition(args):
  f1()
else:
  <statement1>
  .
  .
  <statementN>
```

Statements in else block will also need an access to args.

But I want to hide `f1` and `some_condition` from user of this abstraction, so using an if-else block is out of option. Also I don't want to force a constraint on the user to wrap all statements in a function. Is it possible to do some python magic in the `with` context that allows this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I can get is to use two nested context managers, something like the following:

```
class SkippedException(Exception):
    pass

class SkipContext:
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        return type is SkippedException

class SomeContext:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def __enter__(self):
        if self.arg == 1:
            print "arg", self.arg
            raise SkippedException()
    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        pass

with SkipContext(), SomeContext(1):
    print "body"
```

The `SkipContext` manager essentially catches the `SkippedException` raised by the inner `SomeContext` manager in the case where `arg == 1`.

Note that the syntax of multiple context expressions is only supported in Python 2.7 or later. In earlier versions, you would have to write:

```
with SkipContext():
    with SomeContext(1):
        print "body"
```

The `contextlib.nested` context manager, despite claims in the documentation, doesn't exactly match the semantics of the above nested `with` statement when exceptions are thrown from within `__enter__`, so it doesn't work in this case.

It should be noted that [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) mentions that macros (like context managers) that hide flow control should be discouraged, and references [Raymond Chen's rant against hidden flow control](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050106-00/?p=36783).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can easily create such a context manager as follows.

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def SomeContext(args):
    if some_condition(args):
        f1()
    else:
        yield
```

The user's wrapped code gets executed at the point of the `yield`. I don't think it's a problem that the context manager sometimes does not execute the user's code, but I haven't checked.

Comment: It doesn't work and throws an exception. I even tried wrapping with a wrapper which excepts all exceptions. It then throws an `AttributeError: __exit__` error.